# How to find elements of a string that cannot be part of a non contigous substring?

Tags: c++, performance, hash, substring, dynamic-programming

I want to write a program that takes 2 strings as input, s1 and s2, and determines which characters of s1 couldn't be part of a non contigous  substring that is 2. So after inputting
`123625421454` as s1, and `254` as s2, the program would output
`0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1`, where 1 means that a character can be a part of the substring, and 0 where it cannot.

This problem is really irritating me, since I couldn't find any algorithm that would find the non-contigous sequence without extremely high execution time. Is there even a good solution for this, with less or equal O than O(N)?
I have tried to use hashes and dynamic programming, but no algorithms that I used were good for this circumstance.

EDIT: To clarify, the idea is that you can remove x elements of s1 (x can be 0) and get s2. Elements, which cannot be part of s2 under any circumstances, should be marked as 0, while those that can, should be marked as 1. Hope this helps.

Comment: can you explain "can be a part of a substring" a bit better? what can be a substring of which? How is "this character can be a part of a substring of X" different to "this character is in X"?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes. Sorry for it being so ambigous. It basically means that there is a way to remove certain extra characters of s1 excluding the one in question, and it would be a part of substring s2, so for example s1 = 1234 s2 = 14,1 and 4 could be a part of s2, but 2 and 3 couldn't.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. And examples don't really seem to help (examples are always bad to *define* a rule. They can be helpful to *illustrate* it after a proper definition). Please edit your question to more formally define what you mean.

Comment: @MarcusMüller for any position `i` in `s1`, OP'd like to know if there exists a subset of indices `is` of `s1` that includes `i` and `{s1[is]...}` equals `s2` (where `{}` is in c++-meaning, i.e., array initialization).

Comment: @lorro The `...` in the brackets mean what?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Expansion of indices.

Comment: @lorro and `is` is sorted ascendingly, I guess?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, that's my understanding

Comment: @lorro I like your interpretation, but I'll be very frank: it's not what I could infer from the question. Hope you're right!

Comment: Aren't you just asking for elements of `s1` that are present in `s2`? Because any element of `s1` appearing in `s2` would be part of a 1-element substring. All your examples can be reduced to that.

Comment: @rturrado I think it's not what's asked here, counterexample: 1213, 123 -> 1000 and not 1111.

Comment: @lorro Thanks! I was assuming it couldn't be that simple, but couldn't understand the algorithm either.

Comment: @lorro The counterexample you presented has a mistake. The correct answer for  1213,123 is  1 1 0 1, since there is no solution which would use s1[2] which is the second 1, thats why it "must" be skipped in order to reach the substring, which is 123

Comment: @JULIUSCAESAR777 Then I don't understand, either. My example was s1 = 1213, s2 = 123. What is the substring for 2nd char (s1[1])? I think it only exists for the first.

Comment: @lorro The rule of thumb is that you can erase a number of characters from s1 and get s2. 1213 becomes 123 when you erase s1[2], and there is no way for the s1[2] to be part of 123, because it would require for it to be followed by a 2 and 3, which isn't there, therefore s[2] is a 0, while the other slices are 1's, since they can be a part of the substring. Hope this helpful.

Comment: @JULIUSCAESAR777 Ok, quick shortcut in brain so to say, I understand it now (and the algorithm below works this way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key observation is, if you reach a sub-substring prefix of length k up to a position, then you can have a sub-substring of *any* length less than k up to that position, simply by skipping some of the tail elements. Same holds for postfix. It might sound trivial, but it leads to the solution.

So you'd like to maximize the prefix from front and postfix from tail. Basically, this means that you visit `s1` once from front and once the reverse (with reverse `s2`). In both cases, you'd like to maximize the substring at each point, so you simply advance in `s2` whenever you can. This gives you two array of `size_t` values: longest possible prefix and postfix at the given point. If the sum of those >= the length of `s2` (and there was an increase at the current character in prefix/postfix arrays compared to previous), that means that these can be joined and the result is `1`; otherwise these cannot be joined and the result is `0`.

To do this, you actually need to precalculate if a given char can be an increase at a position in s2. This can be done in O(1) time (see chat for elaboration on that).

Comment: @JULIUSCAESAR777 1. Iterate from front (i1) over s1, starting at front (i2) of s2, incrementing i2 when s1[i1] == s2[i2], storing f[i1] = i2 in each iteration. 2. Iterate from back (i1), starting at back (i2) of s2, decrement i2 ... (same as before), b[i1] = i2. 3. result[i] = f[i] + b[i] >= s2.length().

Comment: @JULIUSCAESAR777 O(N) if you do it right.

Comment: @JULIUSCAESAR777 Yes, you should also check if the character you're standing at can be a continuation (there was an increase in first/back from previous to current).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249701/discussion-between-juliuscaesar777-and-lorro).